# How to draw a linestring from POINT(".........")?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I got this Openlayer Question.

Im trying to get a bunch of points from some objects. Which i believe shouldnt be hard. 
[image: Object overview]

Im am passing the st_astext to the WKT reader to create a `Openlayers.Geometry.Point()` Feature to add to the initial layer that will hold all of the lines. But that doesnt seem to work. Can anyone see what im doing wrong?

```
//Routes for each bridge? 
vesselPosition = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Vessels');
var wkt = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();


$.ajax({
url: "/ajax/getPositions",
dataType: 'json',
success: function(result) {

for (var reportID in result) {
    //Store the object at hand.
    var data = result[reportID];


    //Get all the positions and print them onto the vesselpoisition layer. 
    var positions = data.positions;

    var listOfPoints = new Array();
    for (var index in positions) {
        var positionData = positions[index];
        var point= wkt.read(positionData.st_astext);

        listOfPoints.push(point.geometry);
    }

    var pointmap = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString({points:listOfPoints});

    vesselPosition.addFeatures(pointmap);

};
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString expects array of points for parameter, not object:
http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/LineString-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString.OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString

Answer: Projection issue:

```
point.geometry.transform(
  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
);
```

So try

```
var pointmap = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(listOfPoints);
```

Also pay attention for

```
vesselPosition.addFeatures(pointmap);
```

addFeatures() expects feature, not geometry for parameter. Use:

```
vesselPosition.addFeatures(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(pointmap));
```

For testing purposes, you may draw individual points to map:

```
var point= wkt.read(positionData.st_astext);
vesselPosition.addFeatures(point);
```

Also, check vesselPosition.features.length to determine, whether there are any features.

Comment: Could you paste also json of result. What version of OpenLayers are you using?

Comment: 2.12 
It might be something with the projection. Added the mousecordinate control. and it returns cordinates like 6666474.2399443.

The JSON result is basicly the result of the object that is in the image of the main post.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, that you need to transform points from one coordinate system to other (from 4326 to 900913 would be wild guess). I'll add example to my posting.

Comment: To be sure - what does console.log(map.getProjectionObject().projCode); say?

Comment: `Cannot read property 'projCode' of null`
And
`console.log(map.getProjectionObject());` = null

Comment: Seems, that problem is not in projection. For last thing, you can paste JSON data of result.

Comment: Doesnt look like the last one did anything. Isnt it possible to just make the whole map automatically transform and display in the right projection ?

Comment: JSON: http://pastebin.com/zcHM1XPn
Its just a part of it. The whole json paste is huge and it basicly repeats itself.

Comment: Well it works perfectly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jJVFs/ I notice, that all points have same coordinates in sample data, maybe you just got line with length of 0?

Comment: I got it working here to now! :) with transforming the projection. Is there anyway to make the map display this projection as a default without having to tranform every single Cordinate you put into it? And also make the mousePosition display the longitude and latitude values instead of the XY (Which i guess is the current format). ?